# how to make join consonant and vowel if vowel is come after consonant and assign as one letter in python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-string

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

I want this Output

suppose if Input is
"This is our Home"

['T','hi','s','i','s','o','u','r','ho','me']
hi, ho, me
is one letter

"something is better than Everything"
['so','me','t',hi','n','g','i','s','be','t','te','r','t','ha','n','E','ve','r','y','t','hi','n','g']
so,me,hi,be,te,ha,ve,hi
is one letter

def group_vowels(string):
output = []
substring = ''

```
for i, c in enumerate(string, start=1):
    print('ic',i ,c)
    
    if c in consonants:
        a = substring
        substring = substring + c
        
        output.append(substring)
        substring = ''
      

   
    if c in vowels:
        substring = substring+c
    
        if i == len(string): output.append(substring)
return output
```

print (group_vowels("This is our Home"))

Comment: It depends on how you print the string, but usually it is not a problem of Python, but of your computer (usually font). Python just write standard Unicode string, then a lot of operating system libraries will find out how to display it (also taking into account all "ligatures" and glyphs that depends on context. Try to save to a file and read from it. Shell/terminal/console usually doesn't allow it (most [not all] requires a single cell per codepoint) [but that depends also on the font and settings]

Comment: I tried Above code